# What is this beautiful pink flower plant seen at Bodnant Gardens?

Tags: botany, species-identification

[image]

Seen at Bodnant Gardens, North Wales UK.

Comment: Please include as many details as possible. I can't tell if it's a tree, a shrub, or a tall plant. It certainly is beautiful, though!